# Using Office365 Direct Send SMTP with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, office365, swiftmailer

I'm trying to set up the Direct Send SMTP method for Office365 but I'm getting an error message:

> Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with
>   host {our-tenant-id}.mail.protection.outlook.com [No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-office-3?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fHow-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4#option-2-send-mail-directly-from-your-printer-or-application-to-office-365-direct-send) says that these are the required settings:

```
| Server/smart host | Your MX endpoint, for example, contoso-com.mail.protection.outlook.com
| Port              | Port 25
| TLS/StartTLS      | Enabled
| Email address     | Any email address for one of your Office 365 accepted domains. 
|                   | This email address does not need to have a mailbox.
```

So these are the settings I have used in the `.env` file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST={our-tenant-id}.mail.protection.outlook.com
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=mailbox@ourdomain.co.uk
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I have also checked our SPF record which I can confirm contains the correct entries, according to the documentation.

Has anyone else set this up before or knows where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Is the email address you're trying to send to in your Office365 Organization?

Comment: @AlecJoy Yep, it's internal. I believe that that wouldn't stop a connection from being established in any case

Answer (score 0):

We use a similar setup. Beware that building the connection to office can be a bit slow, so you want to queue the emails to make sure the user doesn't ahve to wait.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mailbox@ourdomain.co.uk
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this method will not work for our use case -- it uses the SMTP authentication client whilst we need to use Direct Send.

Comment: ah, apologies, I read over that rather important piece of your question. Can you test-connect to the server? (e.g.
`openssl s_client -connect {our-tenant-id}.mail.protection.outlook.com -starttls smtp` )

Comment: Could be the case that your outbound firewall (or your ISPs outbound firewall) is blocking port 25 for spam protection reasons. For some of our ISPs we have to request outbound 25 access.

Comment: I've ran the command `s_client -connect {tenant}.mail.protection.outlook.com:25 -starttls smtp` and it doesn't error. I'm not familiar with the tool so I don't know what the output means, it just said "Loading 'screen' into random state - done"

Comment: I would say this indicates there's nothing wrong with the domain setup or the connection ability, but that the problem is inside Swiftmailer. I didn't look into this extensively but this might be related?
https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/545